# How can I stop my Colab notebook from crashing while normalising my images?

Tags: python, machine-learning, crash, google-colaboratory

I am trying to make a model which recognises the emotions of a human. My code and RAM is just fine in the start:
[image: RAM and DISK] 
But when I try to normalise my images, the RAM drastically jumps up 
[image: jumped up RAM]
and then Colab just crashes: 
[image: Crash msg 1]
[image: Crash msg 2]
[image: Crash msg 3]

This is the code block which is causing colab to crash:

```py
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

data = []

for emot in os.listdir('./data/'):
    for file_ in os.listdir(f'./data/{emot}'):
        img = cv2.imread(f'./data/{emot}/{file_}', 0)
        img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
        img /= 255.0 # <--- This is the line that causes colab to crash
        data.append([img, emotions.index(emot)])
```

If I remove the `img /= 255.0`, it doesn't crash, but then I have images which are not normalised!:
[image: Not crashed]
I even tried normalising it in another block:

```py
for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i][0] = np.array(data[i][0]) / 255.0
```

but it doesn't work and still crashes

Comment: You always have the option to move some of the preprocessing into your model training pipeline, which deep learning / ML framework are you using?

Comment: I am using `Tensorflow`.

Comment: Also, what is a model training pipeline? Sorry I am just a beginner so I am new to all of this

Comment: add a possible size of the 'data' list and the size of 'img' as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to go through an example. Firstly let's have a look at the following code.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(100, 32, 32), dtype=np.int16)

print('Present data type', x.dtype)
# What you did
y = x/255
print('Present data type', y.dtype)
# What you should do
z = (x/255).astype(np.float16)
print('Present data type', z.dtype)
```

Output:

```
Present data type int16
Present data type float64
Present data type float16
```

If you look closely, while I am dividing the `x` variable and declaring `y=x/255`, the data type changes to `float64`. If you divide an `int` data type of a NumPy array, by default, it is typecasted to `float64`. Generally, 'float64' contains a larger memory. Therefore while dividing a `int` type NumPy matrix, one should always typecase to shorter datatypes for larger datasets.

If the code you executed fluently runs without the `img /= 255.0` block, then this is the case. After dividing, you should typecast the `img` variable to the lowest possible `float` types, such as, `np.float16` or `np.float32`. However, `np.float16` has some limitations and it is not fully supported by TensorFlow (TF converts it to 32-bit float), you may use `np.float32` datatype.

Therefore, try adding `img.astype(np.float16)` or `img.astype(np.float32)` after the line `img /= 255.0`.

The modified version of the code is given,

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

data = []

for emot in os.listdir('./data/'):
    for file_ in os.listdir(f'./data/{emot}'):
        img = cv2.imread(f'./data/{emot}/{file_}', 0)
        img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
        img = (img/255.0).astype(np.float16) # <--- This is the suggestion
        data.append([img, emotions.index(emot)])
```

Comment: Okay thanks for the reply. I will check if this is working, as soon as I get the time to. Thanks so much again! 

Comment: I have tried it out, and it works! The RAM jumped very little, and the code ran completely, thank you so much! Another problem arose though, now whenever I try to show the images using matplotlib, it says `ValueError: Unsupported dtype`. So do I need to typecast it back to `float32` or something?

Comment: Okay I changed it to `float32` and it is working now. Thanks so much!

Comment: Facing `ValueError: Unsupported dtype` is a common problem (for matplotlib or any other library) if you use `np.float16` datatypes. As I mentioned in the answer, `np.float16` is not widely supported (even, processors do not directly support it). So, mostly you should stick to `np.float32`. If you are facing too much memory issue only then switch to `np.float16`.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975770/python-numpy-float16-datatype-operations-and-float8

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the next step in your pipeline is to create a `tf.data.Dataset` object out of your image corpus, you can use `Dataset.map()` to move your preprocessing into the data loading pipeline to save on memory space. `Tensorflow` has a very well-documented guide on how to do this here -> https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#preprocessing_data

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I never used `tf.data.Dataset`, so it was new to me. I tried looking into it, but I am getting some error (`OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a \`tf.Tensor\` as a Python \`bool\` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.`, when I am trying to map my function to the `Dataset` object).
This issue is also happening on Kaggle, so is it a problem in my code or something?

Comment: I'll need some code to be of more help. However I would highly suggest you follow the `Tensorflow` tutorials before posting every issue you run into, they'll explain it much better than me. Having said that, my suspicion is that your `Tensorflow` version is giving you problems, maybe this will help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59308263/using-a-tf-tensor-as-a-python-bool-is-not-allowed-in-graph-execution-use-ea

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice, I will go over the entire tensorflow tutorial :)