# Using a symbolic `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

I have written a model using tensorflow as follows:

```
learning_rate = 0.1
momentum = 0.9

lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate=learning_rate,
    decay_steps=EPOCH_SIZE,
    decay_rate=0.1
)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=lr_schedule, momentum=momentum, nesterov=True)

input_correct_responses = tf.keras.Input(shape=(26,), name='input_correct_responses')

pe = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(input_correct_responses, z)
ce = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()(input_correct_responses, z)

model = Model(inputs=[input_obscured_word_seen, input_letters_guessed_previously, input_correct_responses], outputs=z)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=pe, metrics=[ce])

progress_printer = tf.keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback(
    on_epoch_end=lambda epoch, logs: print(f"Training - epoch: {epoch + 1}, loss: {logs['loss']}, accuracy: {logs['categorical_accuracy']}"),
    on_train_end=lambda logs: print("Training completed.")
)
```

However, it is spitting out the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[83], line 17
     14 ce = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()(input_correct_responses, z)
     16 model = Model(inputs=[input_obscured_word_seen, input_letters_guessed_previously, input_correct_responses], outputs=z)
---> 17 model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=pe, metrics=[ce])
     19 progress_printer = tf.keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback(
     20     on_epoch_end=lambda epoch, logs: print(f"Training - epoch: {epoch + 1}, loss: {logs['loss']}, accuracy: {logs['categorical_accuracy']}"),
     21     on_train_end=lambda logs: print("Training completed.")
     22 )

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/trackable/base.py:205, in no_automatic_dependency_tracking.._method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    203 self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    204 try:
--> 205   result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    206 finally:
    207   self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training_v1.py:406, in Model.compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights, sample_weight_mode, weighted_metrics, target_tensors, distribute, **kwargs)
    402 if isinstance(self.optimizer, tf.__internal__.tracking.Trackable):
    403     self._track_trackable(
    404         self.optimizer, name="optimizer", overwrite=True
    405     )
--> 406 self.loss = loss or {}
    407 self.loss_weights = loss_weights
...
--> 544   raise errors.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError(
    545       f"{task} is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or"
    546       " decorate this function with @tf.function.")

OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: Using a symbolic `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.
```

I tried changing the order of declaring the loss and metrics as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59308263/using-a-tf-tensor-as-a-python-bool-is-not-allowed-in-graph-execution-use-ea), but still am getting the error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile) states that the loss and metrics arguments of the compile method are supposed to be:

- for the loss, either a `tf.keras.losses.Loss` instance or a callable with a signature `fn(y_true, y_pred)` or a string (the name of one of the predefined keras loss functions).
- For the metrics, a list of either a `tf.keras.metrics.Metric` instance or a callable with a signature `fn(y_true, y_pred)` or a string (the name of one of the predefined keras metric functions).

You're passing the result of the call of the function, which is a Tensor, instead of one of the possibility listed above.

Use this instead:

```
pe = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy
ce = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()

model = Model(inputs=[input_obscured_word_seen, input_letters_guessed_previously, input_correct_responses], outputs=z)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=pe, metrics=[ce])
```

You will need your data pipeline to provide the correct data to the model. Assuming you're using a data generator, it should likely return the following tuple:

```
([input_obscured_word_seen, input_letters_guessed_previously, input_correct_responses], input_correct_responses)
```